# Truelicense Java preferences store other than registry

Tags: java, registry, licensing, preferences, truelicense

For managing the license in my Java application, I want to use [truelicense](https://java.net/projects/truelicense).

Truelicense is using Java Preferences to store license keys and Java preferences on windows OS getting stored in Registry under user root or system root.

But my requirement is different. I want to install my application in USB storage and want to allow application access from that USB device only (from any machine). So, I can't use registry to store the license key.

Is there any other way to store Java preferences like file based or any other. And which is the most secure way.

Is truelicense supports storage other than Preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Java preferences are getting stored in registry on windows platform.
Alternative of the registry is to story preferences in file.

File based preferences can be used for truelicense. Following is the link showing how to implement file based java preferences.

http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/java-preferences-using-file-backing-store

Hope, this will be useful in your case.